# Set DPI to PNG image bitmap in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, png, dpi

I have a simple PNG image, I need to change its DPI and send it to server. I found many alternatives for JPEF, like Exif data/meta data extraction. I did not see any relevant topic for converting DPI for especially PNGs, in Xamarin Android native.

If anyone worked on this yet, your highlights would be appreciated.

Comment: Bitmap provides the **SetResolution** method which could help to specify the dpi value. Try to add the setting for the bitmap file, then convert the bitmap to a png image. Tutorial:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.setresolution?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: Its easy in .NET environment. Here, we are under Android OS.